# Rename detailed information before $ in Terminal

Tags: shell, unix, terminal

I am using Terminal(Mac) for git.

When I use it shows **mySystemName-MacBook-Pro:CurrentWorkingDir mySystemName** before $ sign.
In my case  the whole content is too long and hardly remains few space to write  commands.
I want to rename it and use a alias so that there may be more space for the git commands.

In Short I want From this:

**mySystemName-MacBook-Pro:CurrentWorkingDir mySystemName $**

to this:

**aliasName  $**

Comment: What's `aliasName` supposed to expand to? i.e. why not just `PS1='aliasName $ '`? Also, what's this got to do with git?

Comment: Git bash would give you a linebreak before $

Comment: set your PROMPT to shorter..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PS1="aliasName \$ "`

`man bash`
...

PS1    The  value  of this parameter is expanded (see PROMPTING below) and used as the primary prompt string.  The default value is ‘‘\s-\v\$’’.

...

`PROMPTING`

`\w`     the current working directory, with $HOME abbreviated with a tilde

`\\`     a backslash

...
...
...